# Python HTTP Server

Tags: python, beginner, http, socket, server

This is one of my first times writing Python.  I'm most curious about style and whether `while 1: x,y = socket.accept()` is an acceptable way to wait for new connections.

```
#!/usr/bin/pythonw

import socket
import os


class Server:  

  def __init__(self, directory, host="", port=8123):
    print("Server running on port ", port)
    self.directory = directory
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
    serversocket.listen(5)
    while 1:
      connection, address = serversocket.accept()
      print("Connection received")
      socketfile = connection.makefile("rw")
      request = socketfile.readline()
      print(request)
      url = self.getURL(request)
      print("Serving ", url)
      responseBody = None
      responseCode = 200
      try:
        with open(url, "rb") as requestedFile:
          responseBody = requestedFile.read()
      except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error 404: File not found")
        responseBody = b"404 Error Not Found"
        responseCode = 404
      connection.sendall(self.writeResponse(url, responseCode, responseBody))
      socketfile.close()
      connection.close()
      print("Connection closed\n")

  def writeResponse(self, url, code, body):
    response = "HTTP/1.1 " + ("200\n" if code is 200 else "404\n")
    response = response + "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\n"
    response = response + "Pragma: no-cache\n"
    response = response + "Expires: 0\n"
    response = response + "Connection: close\n"
    if code is 200:
      response = response + "Content-Length: " + str(os.path.getsize(url)) + "\n"
      if ".css" in url:
        response = response + "Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8\n"
      elif ".js" in url:
        response = response + "Content-Type: application/javascript charset=UTF-8\n"
    response = response + "\n"
    return str.encode(response) + body

  def getURL(self, line):
    first = line.find(" ") + 1
    second = line.find(" ", first + 1)
    line = line[(first + 1):second]
    if line == "" or line == "/":
      return self.directory + "index.html"
    else:
      return self.directory + line



if __name__ == "__main__":
  x = Server("/some/path/")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `while 1:`, it would be more natural to write `while True:`

---

Python has an official style guide called [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I suggest to give that a good read and follow the recommendations, especially in terms of indentation and naming rules.

---

Inside the `Server` constructor you have a pointless assignment:

> ```
> responseBody = None
> ```

This variable is reassigned later, no need to initialize it.

---

It's never a good idea to do much in a constructor.
Instead of starting a server to accept connections in the constructor,
I suggest to move that logic to a method.

---

Everywhere you write `x = x + something`, a shorter (and recommended) way is to write `x += something`.

---

These conditions seem a bit weak:

> ```
> if ".css" in url:
>     # ...
> elif ".js" in url:
>     # ...
> ```

Are you sure that `.css` or `.js` won't appear at unexpected places inside the url? If you expect these to be at the end, it would be better to use the more strict conditions:

```
if url.endswith(".css"):
    # ...
elif url.endswith(".js"):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through the code throughly but I do have one small gripe - your naming convention does not follow pythons PEP8. For example `writeResponse` should be `write_response`.  I would recommend taking a look at pythons PEP8 style guide or even a shorthand version of it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have reinvented [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) (Python 3) or [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) (Python 2).

The [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) is vastly more complex than [HTTP 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945).  Don't claim to be an HTTP 1.1 server if you aren't implementing any of the HTTP 1.1 features.

`getURL()` would be more simply written using `line.split()` or a regular expression match.  It fails to do percent-decoding.  Note that since you don't validate the URL, it's possible to **request any file on the server's filesystem** by making a request like `GET /../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.0`.  I consider that to be a security hole.

On supported platforms with Python ≥ 3.3, you can use [`os.sendfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) to copy a file's contents to a socket.

Comment: This is just for learning purposes, but these are great points! Thank you